# instalar paquetes en r

Tags: r, librería

Tengo un sistema operativo Windows 7 de 64 bits y tengo a su vez la version de R 3.2.3 instalada. Pero no puedo instalar algunas librerias, como : tidyr, tidyverse o RPostgreSQL. En la imagen pueden ver que tipo de error me está arrojando. Les agredecería mucho su apoyo. Saludos [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no soy experto pero leyendo el error creo que debes tener instalado el paquete magrittr antes de poder instalar tidyr. Prueba a instalar el paquete magrittr y luego vuelve a intentarlo con tidyr

Comment: Gracias.Ya me enteré que en este tipo de error, lo más sano es forzar esos paquetes por consola!